# Gulp Equivalent to Grunt's Files.Rename

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I have been using Grunt for awhile, and recently decided to try Gulp. I have to say, from what I've seen so far, it looks promising. However, it seems that there are some things that are easy in Grunt that are difficult or impossible in Gulp (as with any 2 similar things, I suppose).

One of these things is renaming the source files for the destination. It's a niche case, I'll admit, but it can be very powerful. In my case, I am using g(r?)u(nt|lp)-sass. I have my SCSS files in folders with "scss" in the name, and I want to put them in a path with "css" as one of the folders, in the same place in the path that the "scss" folder was.

With Grunt, this could be done right in the `files` object, with the `rename` method. For example:

```
grunt.initConfig ({
    sass: {
        move: {
            options: {
                lineNumbers: true,
                compass: true,
                cacheLocation: 'app/.cache/sass'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'app/modules/',
                src: '**/*.scss',
                dest: '',
                ext: '.css',
                rename: function (dest, src) {
                    return 'app/modules/' + src.replace ('scss', 'css');
                    }
            }]
        }
    }
});

require ('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

So far with Gulp, I have:

```
var gulp = require ('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require ('gulp-sourcemaps');
var scss = require ('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('scss:move', function () {
    return gulp.src ('app/modules/**/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe (scss())
        .pipe (sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(**?**));
});
```

**How do I transform the source path in Gulp for the destination path, like the method `files.rename` in Grunt?** I would prefer a relatively simple solution, like a single method, but solutions involving Gulp plugins are OK, as well.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the files to a desintation directory and rename them in the process, leaving the original `scss` folders in the source directory? Or are you trying to move `scss` directories to `css` directories in a source directory? Either way, you want to preserve the directory structure but rename `scss` directories to `css`, right?

Comment: I want to keep the `scss` folders, and create new `css` folders in the same place as each `scss` folder. For example, if there is an `app/scss/app.scss` file, I want to create an `app/css/app.css` file with the CSS compiled from the original Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to preserve the directory structure and change directories named `scss` to `css` while copying from source to destination, correct? If so, what you want is the [gulp-rename plugin](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename). Example:

```js
gulp.task('scss:move', function () {
  var base = './app/modules';

  return gulp.src(base + '/**/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(rename(function (file) {
      file.dirname = path.join.apply(path,
        file.dirname.split(path.sep).map(function (seg) {
          return seg == 'scss' ? 'css' : seg;
        }));
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(base));
});
```

You probably want to do the rename following the source map generation, otherwise the renamed path would be used as the original path in the source maps. There is currently a bug ([#158](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/158)) in gulp-sass that makes it impossible to do the rename before gulp-sass.

Comment: I was looking at that plugin, but it seemed like it would replace the file/folder, instead of adding a new one. I should have known better from Gulp's whole "do one thing & do it right" philosophy.

Comment: @trysis I updated the answer based on your feedback about where the output should go. The plugin is renaming Vinyl (virtual) files in memory, not files on disk. So in this case your source files will be retained.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to look at it sometime this week or next week, once the Christmas rush is over.

Comment: You don't need a separate `base`. According to [the gulp API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase), the default for the base of the destination path is "everything before a glob starts".

Comment: After going through a lot of trial & error, I realized this will not work if the `scss` folder is the last folder before the file (like in my case). `gulp-rename` takes off the slash on either side of the `base.dirname` path. This means you need lookaheads. If I get a chance, I will suggest a change to the answer to deal with this.

Comment: Also, forward slashes do not work on Windows and the sourcemaps have to go before the renaming, not after. I tried to add these suggestions as an edit, but they got rejected as "make no sense as an edit".

Comment: @trysis the `base` you're referring to is what gulp will strip *out* of the `dest()` path. So doing what you suggest would move files from `./app/modules/` to `./`. To do what you suggest you'd have to pass a `base` param of `./`: `gulp.src('./app/modules/**/scss/**/*.scss', {base: './'}).dest('./')`;

Comment: @trysis Ah, good point about the regex not matching the trailing path segment. I made an update that addresses that and the Windows issue.

Comment: @trysis Why do "the sourcemaps have to go before the renaming, not after"? I read your explanation in the suggested edit, but I still don't get it. The original Sass files are loaded into memory as Vinyl files by `gulp.src()` whether you subsequently rename them (in memory) or not. What's the problem with renaming the Vinyl files before piping them to gulp-sass? I'd think what would be an issue is the path used for generating the source maps -- so for that reason maybe you do want to do the renaming after (maybe I had that backwards in my answer).

Comment: Your updates look awesome. Regarding the sourcemaps/renaming issue, if I put the sourcemaps after the rename, they can't find the original paths of the source files. There doesn't seem to be any problem if I put them before, I assume because the entire source file is in each map. Perhaps this is a situation for options like `loadMaps` and `sourceRoot`?

Comment: @trysis So are you getting `Error: File to read not found or unreadable`? I tried it and that's what I get. I haven't traced the logic all the way through, but I get the gist of what's happening in gulp-sass to result in that. It may be a bug -- I'd have to look everything over in detail to figure it out. There are a couple of alternate things that could happen in gulp-sass that would allow it to complete successfully following the rename. In any case, putting the rename after (which results in the source file showing up with your original pathname) is probably what you want anyway, right?

Comment: Probably. I'd have to see how much is involved in reversing the 2 tasks, and whether there would be any value, at least semantically, in doing it. Thanks for checking, anyway.

Comment: @trysis The inability to do the rename before is a bug in gulp-sass. I filed [dlmanning/gulp-sass#158](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/158) on it. In your case the rename probably makes more sense after, but you could just as easily want to do `gulp.src('x.scss').pipe(rename('y.scss'))` before gulp-sass.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think it was a bug. If you couldn't tell, I'm pretty new to `gulp`.